# Unable to connect to UsbDevice

Tags: c#, windows, usb

I'm trying to follow the code sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.usb.usbdevice?view=winrt-22621 to connect to my X52-Pro.

My first stumbling block, was even though the pId and vId are well known, the DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync call was returning nothing. Instead, I'm now passing in an empty string, which is returning a whole collection of devices, which I was able to filter manually to find the forementioned x52 pro. Unfortunately, I'm getting seven different profiles of my joystick...

Ok, so I'm looping over them to see which ones I can actually connect to, using
UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);

However, every single call is throwing an exception. Most are returning The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x80070020), and one is returning A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x8007001F).

I'm at a loss as to determine how/ what is locking the file, as far as I'm aware nothing else should be reading it? I'm not currently playing any games or anything...

```
var myDevices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(string.Empty);

var filteredDevices = myDevices
    .Where(x => x.Name == "X52 Professional Space/Flight H.O.T.A.S.")   ;

Console.WriteLine($"{filteredDevices.Count()} Devices found!");

foreach (var deviceInfo in filteredDevices)
{   
    try
    {
        UsbDevice device = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("connected ok");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"failed to connect to {deviceInfo.Id} ({e.Message})");
    }
}
```